# Why does this kernel_write-call crash?

Tags: linux, file-io, linux-kernel, linux-security-module

Whenever I try to write to a file inside the Linux Security Module I am working on, the kernel crashes with the error message below.

I tried using `vfs_write` instead of `kernel_write`, tried using a normal character array instead of the buffer I am using now, but it always crashes with a similar error message.

What is the cause of the error message and how can I fix it?

I know that writing to a file inside the kernel is bad, but I need to persistently store information.

Below is a simplified version of the code I am using, which is executed in a LSM_HOOK.

```c
static int bnp_file_permission(struct file *file, int mask)
{
     loff_t offset = 0;
     struct file *filp = NULL;
     char *buffer = NULL;

     filp = filp_open("/var/bnp/access.log", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 0);
     if (IS_ERR(filp)) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "BNP: filp_open failed\n");
        return 0;
     }

     buffer = kmalloc(20, GFP_KERNEL);
     memset(buffer, 0x65, 20);

     kernel_write(filp, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &offset); // <-- this lines causes the crash

     filp_close(filp, NULL);
     kfree(buffer);
}
```

Detailed crash log:

```
BUG: stack guard page was hit at 0000000011758623 (stack is 00000000132ba182..0000000012b2f5a4)
```

Uname:

```
Linux bnp 4.19.0-9-amd64 #12 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2 (2020-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Your "detailed crash log" is not detailed at all. The `BUG: ...` line should be followed by a lot more information, including a stack trace and a dump of the registers' contents. Please include it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you register your function as a hook for `file_permissions` check, which is performed inside [security_file_permission](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.132/source/security/security.c#L867) function.

But this function is also executed when you call `kernel_write`:

- it [calls vfs_write](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.132/source/fs/read_write.c#L526),
- which [calls rw_verify_area](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.132/source/fs/read_write.c#L544),
- which [calls security_file_permission](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.132/source/fs/read_write.c#L391).

So you have a **recursion** which simply exhaust the stack.

For break a recursion you need somehow to detect that your hook is called for `/var/bnp/access.log` file **opened by you** and do not open (and write) that file again.

Comment: Sidenote: `sizeof(buffer)` is also wrong and should probably just be `20`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: But replacement 20 to `sizeof(buffer)` cannot cause the fault: Since sizeof(buffer) <= 8 and 8 < 20, writing `sizeof(buffer)` doesn't overflow the buffer and perfectly allowable.

Comment: Yeah sure, I was just pointing that out, it's an unrelated error.